# SQL Server: Find rows rows in Table1 not in Table2 but need data from tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, missing-data

I need to find missing rows, however, I need data from BOTH tables to be returned.  I checked google but did not find a similar question.

```
TableA

thetime  real-time
1        1 pm
2        5 pm
3        7 pm
4        9 pm
5        11 pm

Table2
thedate    transaction_num  thetime
1/1/2000   111                1
1/1/2000   111                4
1/1/2000   111                5
2/1/2000   111                2
2/1/2000   111                4
2/1/2000   222                1
2/1/2000   222                5
```

I need to select the date and transaction_num from Table2 that do not have a time in Table1 so the result from the select statement should have the date and trnsaction number for the missing times not in table2:

```
thedate    transaction_num  thetime
1/1/2000   111                2
1/1/2000   111                3
2/1/2000   111                1
2/1/2000   111                3
2/1/2000   111                5
2/1/2000   222                2
2/1/2000   222                3
2/1/2000   222                4
```

This is the code I have but it is giving me a multi-part binding error:

```
select t2.thedate, t2.transaction_num, t1.thetime
from table2 t2
where not exists(select t1.thetime
                 from table1 t1
                 where t2.thetime = t1.thetime)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this or can point me to an answer?
Most questions in stack overflow for missing rows involve returning data from one table but I need it for 2 tables.

Thank you

Comment: If you're explicitely checking for rows in t2 where `thetime` is not found in t1, what do you expect `t1.thetime` to be in your select clause?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  `thetime` 2, 3 and 1 (from your expected results) do appear in the sample you provided from `Table A`. Can you explain?

Comment: If you are joining on `t2.thetime = t1.thetime`, then why don't you just use `t2.thetime` in your select statement?

Comment: if i use t2.thetime, i will obtain times that I already have.  I need times I dont have for each transaction and date.

Comment: I need the transaction and date but for the times that do not appear in table2.  For example thetime=2 for transaction 111 for date 1/1/2000 does note appear in table 2 so i must have it appear in my results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems all the transaction_nums on all dates should have all the times associated with them. Else it would be treated as missing.

To do this, you can initially cross join the distinct date and transaction_num from table2 and thetime from table1. Then left join on this derived table to get the missing rows.

```
select tt.thedate, tt.transaction_num,tt.thetime
    from (
          select * from (
         (select distinct thedate,transaction_num from table2) a cross join
         (select distinct thetime from table1) b
         ) 
        ) tt
         left join table2 t2 on t2.transaction_num=tt.transaction_num and t2.thetime=tt.thetime and tt.thedate=t2.thedate
where t2.transaction_num is null and t2.thedate is null and t2.thetime is null
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/ORJQ32291)**

Comment: your code in the sample demo is exactly what i was looking for!  thank you so much.  I did  not think the code would be this complicated.  i am surprised.